# Mocked service function not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, mockito, junit5

Here is my code. I can't see why it is not working. The problem is with the line in test :

```
when(applicationUserRepository.findApplicationUserByUsername("testUser"))
        .thenReturn(userToReturnFromRepository);
```

doesn't seem to be doing anything. The function findApplicationUserByUsername returns an empty optional when it should be returning an optional of userToReturnFromRepository.

Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/v1/exercises")
public class ExerciseController {
    
    @Autowired
    ExerciseService exerciseService;

    @GetMapping
    public List<Exercise> getExercises() {

        List<Exercise> exercises = exerciseService.getAllExercises();
        return exercises;
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Service("exerciseService")
public class ExerciseService {
    
    @Autowired
    ExerciseRepository exerciseRepository;

    @Autowired
    ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;
 
    @Transactional
    public List<Exercise> getAllExercises() {
        
        Principal principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        Optional<ApplicationUser> applicationUser = applicationUserRepository.findApplicationUserByUsername(principal.getName());
                
        List<Exercise> exercises = new ArrayList<>();
        if(applicationUser.isPresent()){
            exercises = applicationUser.get().getExercises();
               
            }

        return exercises;
    }
}
```

The test:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
public class ExerciseControllerTest {

    private final MockMvc mockMvc;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @Mock
    ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    public ExerciseControllerTest(MockMvc mockMvc,
            ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.mockMvc = mockMvc;
        this.applicationUserRepository = applicationUserRepository;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @BeforeEach
    public void initMocks() {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
    }

    @Test
    @WithMockUser(username = "testUser")
    public void testGetExercises() throws Exception {
        
         Exercise ex = new Exercise();
         ex.setData("test");
         ApplicationUser user = new ApplicationUser();
         Exercise[] exercises = {ex};
         List<Exercise> list = new ArrayList<Exercise>(Arrays.asList(exercises));
         user.setExercises(list);
         Optional<ApplicationUser> userToReturnFromRepository = Optional.of(user);

        when(applicationUserRepository.findApplicationUserByUsername("testUser"))
        .thenReturn(userToReturnFromRepository);

        mockMvc.perform(get("/api/v1/exercises")).andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(jsonPath("$", hasSize(1)));


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two conflicting things happening in your test:

1. You are using Mockito to init a mock implementation via reflection
2. You have ApplicationUserRepository being Spring injected into the Test class via the constructor.

What ends up happening is this:

1. spring injects applicationUserRepository into the constructor param
2. The applicationUserRepository field is set to the spring injected version in the constructor
3. Mockito inits a new applicationUserRepository mock
4. Mockito replaces the applicationUserRespository field with the mock (i.e. goodbye to your handle on the spring bean that your MVC setup is using!)

The easiest way I can think of to fix it is to use @MockBean instead of the @Mock combined with Constructor injection. @MockBean will instruct Spring to create the mock instance for you, use it, and provide it to you in the test.

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc(addFilters = false)
public class ExerciseControllerTest {

    private final MockMvc mockMvc;
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;
    @MockBean // User MockBean instead of Mock
    ApplicationUserRepository applicationUserRepository;
    
    @Autowired
    public ExerciseControllerTest(MockMvc mockMvc, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.mockMvc = mockMvc;
        //remove the applicationUserRepository injection
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

// remove MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
//...

...
}
```

Comment: It works now as expected. Could you explain me why do I need MockBean and not Mock ? I don't understand how it makes a difference...

Comment: Yes. 

"@Mock" is a pure Mockito annotation. When you call MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this) , class instance will have the mock field populated, but the Spring application context will not know a thing about it.

"@MockBean" is a Spring annotation. Spring will initialize the mock with Mockito AND add it to the Spring application context.